# phpMyAdmin Internal Server Error 500 - invalid JSON

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I am having an issue exporting tables from phpMyAdmin.

**Server version:** `5.6.30` - `MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

**PHP version:** `5.6.22`

**phpMyAdmin version:** `4.6.1`

When I try to export tables I get Error code 500, Internal Server Error.

In the console I get:

> Invalid JSON!Unexpected end of JSON input

I have several similar databases on the same server that I can export from without any issues. Also, if I open individual tables in the problematic database, I can export rows from them without any problems.

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Comment: What do the web server logs say?

Comment: Hi @MarkBrown, can you tell me where I find the web server logs? I haven't been able to work out how to access them.

Comment: Try /var/log/apache2/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the issue arose because I had too many tables in the database for phpMyAdmin. As a workaround, I exported the database to a .sql file using the mysqldump command. I then converted the sql file to csv using this very handy Python script: https://github.com/jamesmishra/mysqldump-to-csv for importation into R.